# Linq expression to get all items in a IList where one field is in another List

Tags: c#, linq

This collection contains the entire database of products:

```
IList<Products> allProducts;
```

This contains just the guids of all the products for this user:

```
IList<Guid> usersProducts;
```

Below is the psuedo code of what I need, i.e. all the product classes in a IList for a given user and the product is also of type == 1.

```
var filteredProducts = (p from allProducts
                       where p.Id in usersProducts && p.Type == 1).List();
```

I can't figure out how to do the SQL query "WHERE IN (..., ...,)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var filteredProducts = (from p in allProducts
                            where usersProducts.Contains(p.Id) && p.Type == 1
                            select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Contains doesn't seem to resolve for me, is it b/c it is an IList? actually wait, I was trying contains on a particular column p.Id.Contains

Comment: think it is missing a select at the end also.

Answer (score 2):

@Samich's answer is correct. It's just a personal preference, but I prefer the method syntax...

`var filteredProducts = allProducts.Where(p => p.Type == 1 && userProducts.Contains(p.Id)).ToList();`

Also, for performance reasons, I swapped the order of your conditionals. If `p.Type` doesn't equal 1, the `Contains` won't execute.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just want a join.

```
var filteredProducts = (from p in allProducts 
                       join u in usersProducts on p.Id equals u.Id
                       where p.Type == 1
                       select p).ToList();
```